# Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler

Tags: android, eclipse

Im stuck and just exhausted, what am I doing wrong here and what do I need to do to get it to work right? Thanks

API 11.

I setup a item in menu.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_add_shindig"
      **android:onClick="showCamera"**
      android:icon="@drawable/shindig_new"
      android:title="@string/shindig_new"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And in mainActivity I added a method to fire off an intent for the camera in another Activity.

```
/**
 * Method to handle launching the Camera view activity.
 * @param view
 */
public void showCamera(View view) {

}
```

But I get this error:

Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler showCamera in class com.shindiggy.shindiggy.MainActivity

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by changing the method to onCameraClick(MenuItem item) and updating the onClick to reflect its name "onCameraClick".

Answer (score 2):

It seems you already solved it, but this is something that has troubled me and is definitely something you would like to read the answer to in the actual documentation. (Just to make sure whatever fix you come up with works on all phones - not just your own...)

Look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource#item-element

The android:onClick property of a **item in the menu** needs a public method with **MenuItem** as its parameter.

Note that this is **different** from, say, a Button!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick

Here, a method taking View as its parameter is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `menuItem` has an `onClick()`. Use `onOptionsItemSelected instead. Use the`menuItemid` to know which item was clicked.

[Menu Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_add_shindig:
        // run your showCamera code or call that method
        return true;
```

[Handling click events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu)

That is for an `OptionsMenu` but it also discusses `ContextMenu`s

Comment: menuItem does have an onClick()

Answer (score 0):

dont use OnClick Method .

use if statement in Method below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_other)
    {
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Other Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_Exit)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Doc - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource#item-element

> android:onClick
>
> Method name. The method to call when this menu item is
> clicked. The method must be declared in the activity as public and
> accept a MenuItem as its only parameter, which indicates the item
> clicked. This method takes precedence over the standard callback to
> onOptionsItemSelected(). See the example at the bottom.
>
> Warning: If
> you obfuscate your code using ProGuard (or a similar tool), be sure to
> exclude the method you specify in this attribute from renaming,
> because it can break the functionality.
>
> Introduced in API Level 11.